# Read csv file with multiple fields

Tags: linux, bash, csv, readfile

I want to read a `.csv` file with a `bash` script. The file only has 1 line of data, but has many fields. Each field is separated by semicolon `;`. For example:

```
1;3;2;1;4;2;4;5;3;2;5;2;7;3;9;14;5
```

The problem here is that what if I want to use the same `bash` script to read another file with the same format, but has different number of fields. For example:

```
1;3;2;1;4;2;4;5;3;2;5;2;7;3;9;14;5;12;3;2;15;4;10;2;5
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: When you say "read," I don't suppose you mean to just `cat file`. What do you want to do with the file contents?

Comment: the script has to read a stream of page address stream via the .csv file, fix frame number to 5, and output the number of page faults occurred in each algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `bash` is quite current, you can use a `bash` array, like this

```
IFS=';' read -a array < file.csv

# Print entire array
echo ${array[@]}
1 3 2 1 4 2 4 5 3 2 5 2 7 3 9 14 5

# Print 7th element of array
echo ${array[7]}
5
```

Alternatively, you can transpose the fields into lines, by translating semicolons into newline characters. That way, the field you want will be the line number.

```
tr ';' '\n' < file.csv
1
3
2
1
4
2
4
5
3
2
5
2
7
3
9
14
5
```

So, now you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
field=1
while read x; do
   echo Field $field, value: $x
   ((field++))
done < <(tr ';' '\n' < file.csv)
```

**Output**

```
Field 1, value: 1
Field 2, value: 3
Field 3, value: 2
Field 4, value: 1
Field 5, value: 4
Field 6, value: 2
Field 7, value: 4
Field 8, value: 5
Field 9, value: 3
Field 10, value: 2
Field 11, value: 5
Field 12, value: 2
Field 13, value: 7
Field 14, value: 3
Field 15, value: 9
Field 16, value: 14
Field 17, value: 5
```